# I am getting "<div>​Manyata embassy,Bangalore</div>" with extra div tags,but i want only Manyata...bangallore to be retrieved in sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {  
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();  
   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current(); 

document.getElementById('AddressId').value = oListItem.get_item("Address");
}}
```

getting `"<div>​Manyata embassy,Bangalore</div>"` with extra div tags,but i want only Manyata...bangallore to be retrieved in sharepoint list

Comment: i also used oListItem.get_fieldVaulesAsText("Address"); .....but it provided me with some [object object] kind of thing ..which i checked on debugger and colud not figure out... so cn anyone please help me get multiline rich text field to retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {  
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();  
   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current(); 

document.getElementById('AddressId').value = strip(oListItem.get_item("Address"));
}}


function strip(html)
{
   console.log(html);
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   console.log("text" + tmp.textContent);
   console.log("html" + tmp.innerHtml);
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Comment: whats changes do i need to make according my code....pls help me..i am very new to sharepoint

Comment: @user52650 check updated answer

Comment: thanks for code but i need to add the resultant value to addressId...how to proceed further..pls let me know bcoz running this code on console gives undefined as result

Comment: @user52650 have you debugged the code? code return the trimmed value.

Comment: where it will return value??... i mean @ which place?

Comment: it directly assign to document.getElementById('AddressId').value

Comment: @user52650 i have updated the code...  run the code and check console. what value printed in console?

Comment: undefined is coming in textbox addressId

Comment: @user52650 press F12.. you can show one window at bottom... select console tab. and check value in that tab

Comment: its coming properly ..thanks a lot for ur time and help

Comment: console.log("text" + tmp.textContent);
   console.log("html" + tmp.innerHtml); which one is right?

Comment: new edited code is working and giving me correct result

Comment: @user52650 marked it as answer so it is useful to other user also

Comment: cn u pls tell me how to get DOB in dd/mm/yyyy format instead of Tue Dec 15 10:30:00 UTC+0530 1992 format?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/javascript-convert-date check this link..

Comment: cn u pls provide me code for above as u did for address part... i tried converting by funcnt but its not working

Comment: please ask another question or provide your code

Comment: function GetFormattedDate(todayTime) {
    //console.log(todayTime);
    var month = format(todayTime .getMonth());
    var day = format(todayTime .getDate());
    var year = format(todayTime .getFullYear());
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}   ................................................. i used this code but not getting value

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175689/i-am-retrieving-date-of-birth-from-list-but-my-o-p-is-coming-as-tue-dec-15-103/175690#175690 check answer