# Output of Date of birth column is coming as Tue Dec 15 10:30:00 UTC+0530 1992

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want output as "15/12/1992". My code is as below:

```
function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {  
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();  
   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();  
      document.getElementById('DOBId').value = GetFormattedDate(oListItem.get_item("DOB"));
    }
}

function GetFormattedDate(todayTime) {
    var month = format(todayTime .getMonth());
    var day = format(todayTime .getDate());
    var year = format(todayTime .getFullYear());
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
```

Comment: and? what exactly do you want to display?

Comment: 15/12/1992.............................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    document.getElementById('DOBId').value = getDate(oListItem.get_item("DOB"));
    }
}

function getDate(stringDate)
{
   var todayTime = new Date(stringDate);
   var month = (todayTime .getMonth() + 1);
   var day = (todayTime .getDate());
   var year =(todayTime .getFullYear());
   return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
}
```

Comment: is it working ?